# How do I copy and paste guides on Adobe xD in Windows?

Tags: adobe-xd

I'm using Adobe XD on Windows 10. I want to copy my guides from one artboard to another. I think I can copy fine. However, when I go to paste, the Paste option is grayed out. What am I doing wrong here?[image: Copy is fine]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although the "copy guides" option does exist, it doesn't seem to work for me either, although, I'm no expert with XD.

A workaround is to duplicate the artboard with the guides, then select and delete the content.

Example

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your guides when you do right click and select "Copy Guides" at the name of your original artboard.
And you can paste them on the name of new artboard which you wanna paste to.